# Create a circular phylogeny with stacked bar in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar, phylogeny, ggtree

I'm attempting to create a circular phylogeny with a stacked bar chart at the end of each tree tip. Below is some example code & data at my feeble attempt. I can create the circular phylogeny as well as the stacked bar-chart, but I can't seem to link the tree tips to the x-axis from the bar chart.

I'm finding some of the code on this site useful, but I still can't piece this together correctly: https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/299-circular-stacked-barplot.html

I've added more detailed example data:

```
#An example of my newick tree file:
(((((species1,species2),species3),species4),((species5,species6),species7)),species8)

#An example of my data file:
SPECIES     CATEGORY     VALUES
species1    A            5
species1    B            10
species1    C            15
species2    A            2
species2    B            8
species2    C            4
species3    A            8
species3    B            5
species3    C            3
species4    A            6
species4    B            5
species4    C            11
species5    A            14
species5    B            5
species5    C            13
species6    A            3
species6    B            4
species6    C            1
species7    A            7
species7    B            9
species7    C            5
species8    A            10
species8    B            4
species8    C            12

ggtree(my_tree, layout='circular') %<+% category_data + ggplot(category_data) + geom_bar(aes(x=as.factor(category_data$SPECIES), y=category_data$VALUES, fill=category_data$CATEGORY), stat="identity", alpha=0.5) + scale_fill_viridis(discrete=TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It's often easiest to debug a polar chart in cartesian coordinates. As  the example data wasn't sufficient to reproduce the issue, I've improvised a bit with a standard dataset.

First, we'll cluster the `mtcars` data and match up the car names with the labels from the clustering.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggdendro)
#> Warning: package 'ggdendro' was built under R version 4.1.1

tree <- hclust(dist(mtcars))
tree <- dendro_data(tree)

data <- cbind(mtcars, x = match(rownames(mtcars), tree$labels$label))
```

Next, we'll plot the dendrogram below a bar chart. We'll make sure that the leaves are on top and that the dendrogram is in some proportion to the bars.

```r
scale <- 0.1
p <- ggplot() +
  geom_col(
    data = tidyr::pivot_longer(data, c(drat, wt, qsec)),
    aes(x = x,
        y = value, fill = factor(name))
  ) +
  geom_segment(
    data = tree$segments,
    aes(x = x, y = -y * scale, xend = xend, yend = -yend * scale)
  )

p
```

[image]

Lastly, we just need to add polar coordinates.

```r
p + coord_polar()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: I'm still having some problems. My tree is a phylo object (from a .newick file) and not a dendrogram, which results in error at this line: data = tree$segments, aes(x = x, y = -y * scale, xend = xend, yend = -yend * scale))   >>>  Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'x' not found. I've looked into converting my phylo object to a dendro object, but I can't seem to make it work. I've updated the example data in the original question to hopefully add some clarity.

Comment: I know nothing about that particular file format.